# Load PHP page content into PhoneGap mobile app

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I am currently developing a mobile application (iOS and Android) HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery Mobile running on PhoneGap to generate an executable that will run on the mobile.

My application in its operation will load dynamic content from PHP page located on my PHP server. PhoneGap cannot generate an application containing PHP files on the phone, I tried in vain to display the content from a page "news.php" my server located in my application.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy solution for your Problem:

***Don't do it this way!***

Create a static html-page, which loads content from your server via ajax-requests. Send proper cors-header and create a domain whitelist for your app.

Explanation:
If I could compromise you webserver, and add a JavaScript to your page, than I would be able, to read / delete, do everything with the devices, which have your app installed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how are you going to create an application. Nothing can prevent you from doing that. Instead of using your files in phonegap www dir you can reference loadUrl to a remote web server, thus sessions will work. And here's an example:

Phonegap + Android :

In your main activity class, method onCreate change loadUrl to:

```
super.loadUrl("http://.../index.php");
```

iPhone + Phonegap ia another story, still it can be done. Because there are a lot of changes here's a tutorial: http://www.joeldare.com/wiki/open_a_url_in_phonegap

One more thing, you must enable an internet connection for the Phonegap.

As you are using the android platform add this line to your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

A viewport meta tag must be set in your html file.

One more thing, if you are creating a iOS app there's a good chance you app will be published because of my first solution. In that case you need to handle it with some kind of web service requests.

Comment: can u please tell something about the file structure i mean where to keep the php files ie. in seperate folder or in the www folder itself and also how to include frames in phonegap..

Answer (score 0):

I just must let you know that apple disallow fetch html pages for your basic functionality, if you do so, they'll reject your app. all of your basic assets should be located on your app.